# How to set the AlertDialog background color

Tags: android

I want to change the My `AlertDialog` background color

> with out using custom dialog

i have tried to set the theme  `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.appContext,r.style.my.Theme);` but its not changing the background color.

Comment: Check if Adding a drawable as background works.  builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.menubackground);

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Android XML resource file under res/values/

You'll want to create a new style that inherits from the default alertdialog theme:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

You can specify either colors or drawable for each section of the AlertDialog.
An AlertDialog will build it's display by combining 3 drawables/colors (top, center, bottom) or a single drawable/color (full).

In a theme of your own override the android:alertDialogStyle style (you can do this within the same XML file):

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Override your application's theme in the AndroidManifest within the application tag:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Now that you've defined your application's theme, any attributes overridden in your theme will resonate throughout your app.
For example if you also wanted to change the color of your application's title bar:
You would first define a  new style that inherits from the default attribute

```
<style name="MyBackground" parent="android:WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

and just add the new overridden item to your theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MyBackground</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the background color of the hole dialog window?

Not tested, only looked up API Ref.

AlertDialog is extending Dialog.

In Dialog is the Method:

```
getWindow()
```

The Window http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html Ref shows the method:

```
setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable drawable)
and
setBackgroundDrawableResource (int resId)
```

Could work.

Comment: This is changing the whole window colour i want only change the alert dialogue portion not the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
            doStuff();
        }
    });

    FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.body /*CURRENTLY an ERROR*/);
    f1.addView(findViewById(R.layout.dialog_view));


    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.body);
    f1.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, f1, false));

 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

This code will set your dialog to a custom layout file called dialog_view from there you can do what ever you want to that custom layout.

You want to set the background in that custom layout so in your layout set the background on the root layout object

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:background="#000000"
              />
```